# C++ templated function with templated class as return value

Tags: c++, templates, undefined-reference

I have this Java code:

```
public interface Adapter<FROM,TO> {
    /**
     * Adapts something from one type to a type. 
     * @param f
     * @return
     */
    public TO adapt(FROM f);
    
    /**
     * Chains adapters. 
     * 
     * @param <NEXT>
     * @param next 
     * @return a new adapter that takes the output of this adapter and 
     * adapts to something of type NEXT.
     */
    public default <NEXT> Adapter<FROM,NEXT> chain(Adapter<TO,NEXT> next){
        Adapter<FROM,TO> x=this; 
        return new Adapter<FROM,NEXT>(){
            @Override
            public NEXT adapt(FROM f) {
                return next.adapt(x.adapt(f));
            }
        };
    }
```

I'd really like something similar in C++. The best I've done so far is:

```
#ifndef ADAPTER_H
#define ADAPTER_H
 
template <typename FROM, typename TO>
class Adapter
{
  public:
  TO adapt(FROM f);
 
  template <typename NEXT> Adapter<FROM, NEXT> chain(Adapter<TO, NEXT> arg)
  {
    class UnNamed: public Adapter<FROM, NEXT>
    {
      public: 
      Adapter<TO, NEXT> outer;
      UnNamed(Adapter<TO, NEXT> arg)
      {
        outer = arg;
      }
      NEXT adapt(FROM from)
      {
         outer.adapt(Adapter::adapt(from));
      }
     };
     return UnNamed(arg);
   }
};
 
#endif
```

but it fails with undefined reference errors. I'd really like to keep the api as close to the Java as possible, but I can't figure how to get the nested class to exist in a referenceable way.

Comment: Can you prove a [mcve]?  It'd be useful to see how you're calling this code.

Comment: You have not defined `Adapter::adapt`, only declared it.

Comment: "but it fails with undefined reference errors" Please [show these exactly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close.

In Java, `interface`s have to be implemented by concrete classes, and `interface` methods are virtual and must be overriden in those classes.  In the case of your example, the use of the `default` keyword on the `chain()` method allows Java to generate its own class to implement the `Adapter` interface that `chain()` returns.

In C++, you can do something similar, except that there is no equivalent to Java's `default` keyword (C++ has a `default` keyword, but its meaning is very different), so you need to explicitly define your own class type to implement your virtual interface.  You tried doing that, however polymorphism doesn't work unless you call the virtual methods via pointers/references to objects, otherwise you can suffer from [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/).  In a way, Java also enforces this rule, because all objects in Java are reference types, only fundamental types are value types (whereas in C++, classes can also be used as value types).

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <memory>

template<typename FROM, typename TO>
class Adapter
{
public:
    /**
     * Adapts something from one type to a type. 
     * @param f
     * @return
     */
    virtual TO adapt(FROM f) = 0;
    
    /**
     * Chains adapters. 
     * 
     * @param <NEXT>
     * @param next 
     * @return a new adapter that takes the output of this adapter and 
     * adapts to something of type NEXT.
     */
    template<typename NEXT>
    std::unique_ptr<Adapter<FROM, NEXT>> chain(Adapter<TO, NEXT> *next)
    {
        class ChainedAdapter : public Adapter<FROM, NEXT>
        {
        private:
            Adapter<FROM, TO> *x; 
            Adapter<TO, NEXT> *next;
        public:
            ChainedAdapter(Adapter<FROM, TO> *x, Adapter<TO, NEXT> *next)
                : x(x), next(next) {}

            NEXT adapt(FROM f) override {
                return next->adapt(x->adapt(f));
            }
        };

        return std::make_unique<ChainedAdapter>(this, next);
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/z1gpIJ)

Although, I suppose you could also get away with making `chain()` return a new `ChainedAdapter` without creating it dynamically, if you are very careful with the returned object and don't use it in any way that would slice it:

```cpp
#include <memory>
     
template<typename FROM, typename TO>
class Adapter
{
public:
    /**
     * Adapts something from one type to a type. 
     * @param f
     * @return
     */
    virtual TO adapt(FROM f) = 0;
     
    /**
     * Chains adapters. 
     * 
     * @param <NEXT>
     * @param next 
     * @return a new adapter that takes the output of this adapter and 
     * adapts to something of type NEXT.
     */
    template<typename NEXT>
    auto chain(Adapter<TO, NEXT> *next)
    {
        class ChainedAdapter : public Adapter<FROM, NEXT>
        {
        private:
            Adapter<FROM, TO> *x; 
            Adapter<TO, NEXT> *next;
        public:
            ChainedAdapter(Adapter<FROM, TO> *x, Adapter<TO, NEXT> *next)
                : x(x), next(next) {}
     
            NEXT adapt(FROM f) override {
                return next->adapt(x->adapt(f));
            }
        };
     
        return ChainedAdapter(this, next);
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/f0ur9M)

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid direct Java code translation.

One C++ way is to embrace values.

```
template<class Sig>
struct adapter;
template<class Out, class In>
struct adapter<Out(In)>:std::function<Out(In)>
{
  using std::function<Out(In)>::function;
  template<class Next, class Result=std::invoke_result_t<Next const&, Out>>
  adapter<Result(In)> chain( Next next ) const& {
    auto tmp=*this;
    return std::move(tmp).chain(std::move(next));
  }
  template<class Next, class Result=std::invoke_result_t<Next, Out>>
  adapter<Result(In)> chain( Next next ) && {
    return [self=std::move(*this), next=std::move(next)](In in)->Result {
      return next(self(std::forward<In>(in)));
    };
  }
};
```

there we go.

```
adapter<int(double)> rounder=[](double d){return std::floor(d);};
adapter<double(std::istream&)> double_reader=[](auto&is){double d; is>>d; return d;};
adapter<int(std::istream&)> int_reader=double_reader.chain(rounder);
std::cout << int_reader(std::cin);
```

etc.

These adapters are polymorphic value types.  And you can chain them with function pointers, lambdas, std functions, or other function objects

The `x.adapt(foo)` call is spelled `x(foo)` in the above code.  Objects whose primary purpose is to be called ... can use `operator()` to make then callable.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/GqTrvan77).

Design:

I made `std::function` do most of the heavy lifting.  It is a polymorphic value type that supports calling and nullability.

We simply inherit from it, forward constructors, and add in a `.chain` method that checks compatibility and deduces the return type.

We can extend adapters to support many-one adaption easily.  The first step is to support multiple inputs just by adding a bunch of `...`s in the right spot:

```
template<class Sig>
struct adapter;
template<class Out, class... In>
struct adapter<Out(In...)>:std::function<Out(In...)>
{
    using std::function<Out(In...)>::function;
    template<class Next, class Result=std::invoke_result_t<Next const&, Out>>
    adapter<Result(In...)> chain( Next next ) const& {
        auto tmp=*this;
        return std::move(tmp).chain(std::move(next));
    }
    template<class Next, class Result=std::invoke_result_t<Next, Out>>
    adapter<Result(In...)> chain( Next next ) && {
        return [self=std::move(*this), next=std::move(next)](In... in)->Result {
            return next(self(std::forward<In>(in)...));
        };
    }
};
```

Now, the `first.chain(second)` syntax doesn't work as well with multiple inputs for `second`.  We can add another method:

```
template<class Sig>
struct adapter;
template<class Out, class... In>
struct adapter<Out(In...)>:std::function<Out(In...)>
{
    using std::function<Out(In...)>::function;
    template<class Next, class Result=std::invoke_result_t<Next const&, Out>>
    adapter<Result(In...)> chain( Next next ) const& {
        auto tmp=*this;
        return std::move(tmp).chain(std::move(next));
    }
    template<class Next, class Result=std::invoke_result_t<Next, Out>>
    adapter<Result(In...)> chain( Next next ) && {
        return [self=std::move(*this), next=std::move(next)](In... in)->Result {
            return next(self(std::forward<In>(in)...));
        };
    }
    template<class...First>
    adapter<Out(First...)> consume( adapter<In(First)>... src)&&
    {
        return [self=std::move(*this), ...src=std::move(src)](First... first)->Out
        {
            return self(src(std::forward<First>(first))...);
        };
    }
    template<class...First>
    adapter<Out(First...)> consume( adapter<In(First)>... src) const&
    {
        auto tmp = *this;
        return std::move(tmp).consume( std::move(src)... );
    }
};
```

but that is going a bit far, no?

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/MzMPYnE6P).

There are some who are leery about inheriting from a value type (like `std::function`) in a non-polymorphic manner.  Here, I'd argue that almost nobody in their right mind stores pointers to `std::function`s; those that do, often are doing a `shared_ptr` trick (which handles polymorphic destruction).

However, if you are concerned, you can do this:

```
template<class Out, class... In>
struct adapter<Out(In...)>
{
  using F = std::function<Out(In...)>;
  F f;
  // forward call operator
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const
  -> std::invoke_result_t<F const&, Args&&...>
  {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  // default all special member functions:
  adapter()=default;
  adapter(adapter const&)=default;
  adapter(adapter &&)=default;
  adapter& operator=(adapter const&)=default;
  adapter& operator=(adapter &&)=default;
  ~adapter()=default;
  // forward a few useful operations and ctors:
  explicit operator bool() const { return (bool)f; }
  template<class Fin> 
  requires (!std::is_same_v<Fin, adapter> && std::convertible_to<Fin, F>)
  adapter( Fin fin ):f(std::forward<Fin>(fin)) {}
```

then add in the `.chain` methods.

As you can see, this adds a fair bit of code.  [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/fT3ea5PeP).

Comment: I doubt that inheriting from `std::function` really reflects C++ value

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Inheriting a value type from another value type is a perfectly good idea, especially when slicing isn't a problem; the std function slice of the adapter above is *correct*.  Only if you are storing owning dumb pointers to std function (... and why are you doing that) is there a problem (including owning unique ptrs without a destroy function; but again, a unique ptr to a std function is serious code smell.)